# Is it possible to show a database record in GridView spanning in two rows?

Tags: asp.net, database, gridview

I have a database record with fields e1 to e14 and v1 to v14 I would like to show them in gridview so each e is in upper row and the correspondent v is in lower row.

Is it possible or should I write  a custom function to display them in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at GridView's Template Field option. Template Field gives you control as to how render the UI. In your case you will create two TR one for Field E and other for V.

This article will give you core concept and you can develop as per your requirement.[ASP.NET TemplateFields in Grid view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs)